# how to get the latest in django model

Tags: django, django-models

In this model:

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Rank = models.ForeignKey(RankStructure)
    date_promoted = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Rank.Name.order_by('promotion__date_promoted').latest()
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception Value:    

'str' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

I want the latest Rank as default.  How do I set this?

Thanks.

Update #1

Added Rank Structure

```
class RankStructure(models.Model):
    RankID = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    SName = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    LongName = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    GENRE_CHOICES = (
        ('TOS', 'The Original Series'),
        ('TMP', 'The Motion Picture'),
        ('TNG', 'The Next Generation'),
        ('DS9', 'Deep Space Nine'),
        ('VOY', 'VOYAGER'),
        ('FUT', 'FUTURE'),
        ('KTM', 'KELVIN TIMELINE')
    )
    Genre = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    SPECIALTY_OPTIONS = (
        ('CMD', 'Command'),
        ('OPS', 'Operations'),
        ('SCI', 'Science'),
        ('MED', 'Medical'),
        ('ENG', 'Engineering'),
        ('MAR', 'Marine'),
        ('FLT', 'Flight Officer'),
    )
    Specialty = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SPECIALTY_OPTIONS)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=image_upload_handler, blank=True)
```

This is the Rank_structure referenced by Rank in Class Rank.
THe User Foreign key goes to the standard User table.

Comment: What do you mean latest `Rank`? It is not possible with you current structure you have provided. `Rank` object have only one `RankStructure`, but `RankStructure` have many `Rank`s

Comment: ok.  I have a table for RankStructure and a table for User.  They are many to many, so I built Rank.  Rank adds the date effective by using date_promoted.  So, when given a User, and I call User.rank, I want the latest Rank.

Comment: Please add your User and RankStructure models

Comment: Your question still doesn’t make sense.  You want `__str__` called an instance of the `Rank` object to print what?  The same string for all `Rank` instances?

Comment: What is it your are trying to order by? I don't see a date field on `RankStructure`.

Comment: In rank. That's the ordering of the rsnk_structure to the user.  Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you’re getting an error is because `self.Rank.Name` is not a `ModelManager` on which you can call `order_by`.  You’ll need an `objects` in there somewhere if you want to call `order_by`.  We can’t help you with the django formatting for the query you want unless you also post the model definitions as requested by several commenters.  That said, I suspect that what you want is something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.objects.filter(Rank_id=self.Rank_id).order_by('date_promoted').latest().User.Name
```